# Saving the last value used in an ISR

Tags: avr, interrupts

I am using a level-triggered interrupt. During the interrupt OCR1A increases and the servo moves. I want to save each value of OCR1A when the pin returns to its previous level. So far I have only been able to save one value, but I want to save all values of OCR1A whenever program stops calling the ISR.

```
// Program to use External (Hardware) Interrupts of AVR Microcontroller (ATmega16)
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

volatile unsigned int temp=65;
void Wait()
{
    uint8_t i;
    for(i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
        _delay_loop_2(0);


    }

}


/***** Function To Initialize Ports*****/
void init_ports()
{
DDRA = 0xFF;
PORTA = 0x55;
OCR1A=temp;
}

/***** Function To Initialize Interrupts*****/
void init_interrupts()
{
cli();  //Disable Global Interrupts
GICR =(1<<INT0);    //Set Bit6 of GICR to unmask INT0 interrupt.
MCUCR =(0<<ISC00);  //Configuring MCUCR for Rising Edge interrupt for INT0
sei();  //Enable Global Interrupts
}

/***** Interrupt Service Routine For INT0*****/
ISR (INT0_vect)
{
PORTA=~PORTA;
OCR1A=OCR1A+1;
temp=OCR1A;
_delay_ms(100);
if(OCR1A==305)
{  OCR1A=65;
   _delay_ms(300);
}
}


/***** Main Function *****/
int main(void)
{
unsigned int i;
//Configure TIMER1
    TCCR1A|=(1<<COM1A1)|(1<<COM1B1)|(1<<WGM11);         //NON Inverted PWM
    TCCR1B|=(1<<WGM13)|(1<<WGM12)|(1<<CS11)|(1<<CS10);  //PRESCALER=64 MODE 14(FAST PWM)

    ICR1=2499;  //fPWM=50Hz (Period = 20ms Standard).

    DDRD|=(1<<PD4)|(1<<PD5);    //PWM Pins as Out
    OCR1A=65;
init_ports();
while(1)
{
init_interrupts();
for(i=65;i<=temp;i++)
{ OCR1A=i;
   _delay_ms(100);
   if(i==temp-1)
   {  OCR1A=65;
       Wait();

   }
}

}
}
```

Comment: Somehow the program is not shown properly here

Comment: I edited it using the "code sample" button.  But you need to supply a lot more context information to make this a good question.

Comment: Thank you mark. What information would be needed? Can you suggest something? I am working on a robotics project. I am controlling the the servos through switches using interrupt. I want that the positions I give to the servos manually should be saved in an array so that I can make the robot to work autonomously. One more thing, I am using level triggered interrupt here.

Comment: It is *very* unclear what you're asking. I posted the naive answer, but that probably isn't *quite* what you want to know. But we can't tell.

Comment: I am using level triggered interrupt. During the interrupt the OCR1A value increases and the servo moves. I want to save the values of OCR1A when the interrupt stops. So far I have been successful to save only one value. But I want to save all values of OCR1A whenever program returns from ISR. My English isn't that great, so I am having problem explaining things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger on level change interrupt.

In the ISR:

- change the edge on which in terrupt is triggered (rising to falling or vice versa),
- check, which edge has triggered the interrupt and set a global variable buttonIsPressed,
- save the OCR1A value if it was button release.

In the main loop - increase OCR1A if buttonIsPressed==true.

In addition, NEVER delay() in ISR code.

On another hand, I think it is possible to solve this without using interrupts. Button bounce is the problem here, unless you debounce the button in hardware (using RC filter for example) - while button press is in progress, you will get some noise (rapid on/off) on the button line. It depends on the quality of button, but generally is unavoidable. Usually all human actions are slow when compared to MCU speed, so no need to use interrupts here. I'd suggest such a solution in the main loop:

- is the button pressed? (really pressed, not just a random bounce)
- if yes, increase OCRA1, delay a bit so human can see the results, check the button, if still pressed, repeat
- if the button is released (realy released, not a random bounce), save OCR1A value

There are plenty of resources on button debouncing in this site and the internet in general.

Comment: From the second option you gave I am able to save only one value of OCR1A(the last one). Can you suggest something to save multiple values of OCR1A (2 or 3 values).

Comment: you need to create an array of values you save and an index variable. increase index variable after each save, until you have collected as many samples as you need. Note that you have to not overflow the array, last item you can save is array length - 1.

Comment: also name your variables properly, believe me, there is a great benefit in keeping your code tidy and clear.